# Moving local storage in native iOS app to React Native app

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, react-native-web

I currently have a native iOS app written in Obj-C & swift and there are a few user settings that are stored locally on the device.

The app is being re-written in React Native and once the new React Native app is released, I'm curious if it will have access to the local storage data from the existing native iOS app.

Comment: Yes, assuming the bundle ID is still the same, you'll have access to the same storage/settings you had before.

Comment: Excellent!  That's what I was looking for.  Thanks @jnpdx.  If you put this as an answer, as small as it is, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the bundle ID is still the same (eg it is an upgrade in-place and not an entirely different app(, you'll have access to the same storage/settings you had before, whether that's local file storage, UserDefaults, etc.

Depending on where things are stored you *may* need to investigate non-Javascript solutions for accessing that data (such as UserDefaults, for example), but there are robust systems for using native code within React Native apps, so nothing should be impossible to access if your original app's code had access to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you had some custom made code, that you need to run, you can always integrate the previous code into react native application and communicate from native to react native and vice versa.

See
https://reactnative.dev/docs/communication-ios